# Spring Integration queue: Where does the queue resides?

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to Spring integration;If i understand right, spring integration has 3 key players;

1 Publisher

2 Subscriber

3 Channel.

I can understand the Publisher, subscriber frameworks where DB/File system is used as queue. Where does spring integration queue resides? If publisher and subscriber are individual process by itself, how do they share channel? Is channel accessible to both Publisher process and subscriber process because they run in same JVM?

Does that mean that, if publisher runs in one machine and subscriber runs in another machine, can't we use Spring integration?

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Integration is Framework for developing integration solutions. It is lightweight and doesn't provide a Broker solution.

If your producer and consumer are in separate JVMs, you really have to use third-party Messaging Broker like ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, Apache Kafka, Hazelcast etc.

Spring Integration just only provides building blocks, everything rest is up to use. The main feature of the channel that you always can switch it into different implementations without impacting producer and consumer. Right, if both producer and consumer are in the same JVM, there is no reason in the external network communication. In most cases you even don't need to use `QueueChannel` - the `DirectChannel` is enough to perform consuming in the producer's thread.

See [Message Channels](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @Artem Bilan. I understood that Spring-Integration is to enterprise design pattern for designing application not meant to be used as broker to be used across applications; I mean, spring integration supposed to help in intra-process communication Not as inter-process communication.

Comment: OK. What is your concern then? Imaging you have JMS producer and JMS consumer. And both of them on different machines. So, do you stop to use JMS API? Why you aren't not going Spring Integration then? Just pay attention that Spring Integration provides JMS channel adapters, as well as adapters for many other technologies and protocols which works pretty well even without Spring Integration, but with that you unify integration layer in your application(s).